# Is it well-defined behavior to create a variable in an unreachable statement?

Tags: c++, memory, c++11, switch-statement

I have a program with a `switch` statement similar to this:

```
switch(n)
{
case 0:
    /* stuff */
    break;

    int foo;
case 1:
    foo = 5;
    break;
case 2:
    foo = 6;
    break;
}
```

Notice the `int foo;` between `case 0` and `case 1`. This statement is unreachable: if you walk through the program, you'll never step over it.

This compiles without warnings or errors with Clang, but it seemed to be jacked up when I ran it (though that could be due to other causes).

Is it well-defined behavior to declare a variable in an unreachable statement and use it in reachable statements, and is it going to work?

Comment: It's not good practice, no matter what the spec says, and should probably be fixed anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is well-defined behavior as long as the variable has trivial construction, and has (approximately) 
the same effect as if the variable was declared in a larger scope.

If any initialization is needed, you'll get an error.

section 6.7 says

> It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that jumps from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has scalar type, class type with a trivial default constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of these types, or an array of one of the preceding types and is declared without an initializer.

Comment: God, I hate reading programming language specifications.  I don't really see how this paragraph is relevant either.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Why not? The paragraph defines when it is legal to "skip" a variable declaration and jump directly to a point where the variable is used, and when it is not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, it says that a program that jumps from before the declaration of a variable to someplace after it is well-formed as long as the variable doesn't need initialization.